# What does "puffs" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, literature

> And a Centre of Advanced Technology isn't going to be allowed to
> regard literature as a technology, even though it is. Look at the
> authors already out of print and likely to remain so. The levelling's
> going to reach the limit. Not even technical brilliance in the
> performing arts is going to be allowed. Them kids what sings and plays
> the guitar does all right, don't they, earning millions though they
> loses it all in tax, and they never had a bleeding lesson in their
> bleeding **puffs**.
>
> *- 1985 by Anthony Burgess*

Puff has several meanings according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/puff) as a noun:

1. a small amount of smoke, air, or something that can rise into the air in a small cloud
2. a piece of food made of puff pastry filled with something sweet or with food such as cheese
3. an act of smoking

But none of them is proper for the text. Note that the text is written in Workers' English which is a fictional language in the book 1985.

Answer (score 7):

Puff=breath=life. British working-class slang. Never in my puff = never in my life.

> Phrases - in all one's puff- British informal - In one's whole life.

[Puff (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/puff)

Comment: I don't think this usage has any particular association with Cockneys. It's more a Northern/Midlands usage (Burgess grew up in Manchester, which might partly explain why he still used the term when it had largely gone out of fashion).

Comment: Haha - upvoted after the edit. The rest of the world needs to know that not all British working-class people are Cockneys. (Just as they need to know that not all Britons come from England! :)

Comment: The phrase "Not on your nelly" (No chance!) is considered to be Cockney rhyming slang for "Not on your life!" (Nelly Duff, whoever she was = puff = life.)

Comment: @KateBunting - many suppose that there never a person called Nelly or Nellie Duff. i have heard that some Scots say 'Nellie Puff'.

Comment: @KateBunting: Many people seem to assume that *all* rhyming slang in BrE is *Cockney*, but obviously it's at least *possible* that ***Not on your Nellie**!* originated outside of London (perhaps Scotland). [Partridge](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22not+on+your+nellie%22+%22from+not+on+your+life%22) notes the specifically *Irish* variant ***Not on your Nannie**!* And I'm sure Irish and Scottish slang usages are on average far more connected to each other than either of them are to *Cockney* slang. Also, for what it's worth, I used to have a Scottish Auntie Nellie myself for real!

Answer (score 6):

It's a very dated slang usage, defined [in the full OED as](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/154180?rskey=5NB5uK&result=1#eid)...

> **puff** g. colloquial (originally and chiefly British)
> *Life; span or length of life; esp. in in (all) one's (born) puff: in a person's experience, in all a person's life (chiefly in negative contexts).*

I wouldn't recommend using it with this sense today. Most native speakers under 70 probably wouldn't understand you.

Comment: I'm under 70, and I know it. Someone said it on 'EastEnders' recently.

Comment: Eastenders scriptwriters aren't necessarily concerned with what Cockneys *actually* say!

Comment: Tell me abaht it! Honesty (or snobbery) compels me to confess that I don't actually watch the programme, but my wife does, and I can hear it while I am at the computer.

Comment: I am under 70 by 7 months.

Comment: Leave it aht, mate! I don't actually watch the programme either, but my ex-wife does/did. Anyway, nowadays I share my house with a dyed-in-the-wool Cockney, and when I just asked him about this one he said he's only ever heard ***puff = life*** from *Scottish* speakers.